# DB2 Select with group by and sum based on another column

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following situation:

```
ACCT_TABLE

ID|TYPE|AMT
--+----+---
A |CR  |  5
A |DR  |  5
B |CR  |  2
B |CR  |  4
B |DR  |  2
B |DR  |  2
C |CR  |  1
C |CR  |  1
```

I am trying to build a query that produces the following results:

```
DESIRED RESULT

ID|BAL
--+---
A |  0
B |  2
C |  2


ACTUAL RESULT

ID|BAL
--+----
A | -10
B |  -8
C |   2
```

I'm not sure how to sum the values in amount based on the value in the `TYPE` column.

I have the following:

```
    select id, sum(
        case
        when
            type = 'CR'
            then AMT
            else -AMT
        end
    ) as BAL
    from acct_table
group by id;
```

Comment: so the only thing you missing is `GROUP BY ID` and you should be done

Comment: Sorry, I do have that. I just missed copying it here.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it is summing, but not subtracting DR's. It just appends a `-` to those records.

Comment: replace `-AMT` with `(AMT*-1)`

Comment: Bal for B should be 2 instead 4 because you got +2,+4,-2,-2

Comment: Tried (AMT*-1)... same result.

Comment: What is data type of `AMT` column

Comment: AMT -> DECIMAL with length of 10

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I was once scolded here for using multiplication where subtraction would suffice: `0-AMT` produces the same result and should conceivably perform better.

Comment: @JTFRage were you able to figure out what issue caused this?

Comment: Yes I was, and it was correct. There was no problem. Just happened to have accounts that either had CR or DR. So the sum would either be a credit or a debit (+/-) so I wasn't seeing changes. I however did have one account lol that changed. LOL I just read my data wrong and wasn't checking manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your query in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server),[oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) and it produced desired results.

**Your Query**

```
SELECT id
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'CR' THEN AMT
                 ELSE -AMT
            END) AS BAL
    FROM acct_table
    GROUP BY id;
```

---

**My Query**

```
SELECT id
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'CR' THEN AMT
                 ELSE ( AMT * -1 )
            END) AS BAL
    FROM acct_table
    GROUP BY id;
```

[oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) test - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b8cb/1

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) test- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b8cbd

[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) test - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b8cb/1

Please verify that data in your table matches what you have shown in the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you change `-AMT` to `AMT * -1`?

Comment: to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a query performing summing like that in DB2 (9.7 LUW), and it also worked.

There appears to be nothing wrong with your query; it must be something else.